# MATLAB rectangular window

Tags: matlab, window

How can I plot a stem of rectangular window with a length of 25 in the range of 0≤n≤24 ?

I did it as follows:

w = rectwin(25)
stem(w)

Is this correct since the first sample (i.e. n=0) is not showing as part of the window. 
Also, when using rectwin() should I input 25 or 24 as the parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the number of points required for your window as input to rectwin function. The plot does not show value for n=0 because MATLAB indexing starts at 1. For a 25 point window, you should have 25 values and the plot shows values plotted from 1 to 25. If you want it to start at 0, you can pass x-axis values to the stem function.

```
w = rectwin(25); stem(0:numel(w)-1,w);
```

Or you can use the wvtool to inspect the window which will show you x-axis from 0 and also a frequency domain view for the window.